# Kubernetes Tolerations - why do we need to defined "Effect" on the pod

Tags: kubernetes

When defining the Taints & Tolerations, we defined the Taint as below:

```
kubectl taint nodes node1 key1=value1:NoSchedule
```

Now any pod that does not have toleration defined as below will not be scheduled on node1. And the one that has toleration defined, gets scheduled on this node. But, why do we need to define NoSchedule on the POD? It is already defined on the node.

```
tolerations:
- key: "key1"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value1"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

What impact does it have if:

1. The node effect is NoSchedule

```
kubectl taint nodes node1 key1=value1:NoSchedule
```

2. But the POD toleration is NoExecute

```
tolerations:
- key: "key1"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value1"
  effect: "NoExecute"
```

Note: I understand that it is trying to match not just "taint value" but also the "taint effect". But is there any use case for matching "taint effect" as well?

> tolerations.effect (string) Effect indicates the taint effect to match. Empty means match all taint effects. When specified, allowed values are NoSchedule, PreferNoSchedule and NoExecute.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What impact does it have if:
>
> 1. The node effect is NoSchedule
>
> kubectl taint nodes node1 key1=value1:NoSchedule
>
> 2. But the POD toleration is NoExecute

Pod will not be schedule on the node where it failed to tolerate, eg. your sample pod will not be schedule on node that tainted with `NoSchdule` because it only tolerates `NoExecute`.

`...use case for matching "taint effect"`

Not sure what it means here; but it is possible to tolerate a key with any effect by only specified the key and value.

Comment: Concerning the "use case" question, I understand it as "why is this knob even there?", something I also ask myself, especially given that the documentation and all of the admittedly small number of examples I've found regarding this topic start out including the taint effect match. I fail to imagine why I would ever want to use it, though the examples make it out to be important.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question, and I stumble on this post. I some of this idea help me understand it:

1. taint and toleration **should work together** [from the docs 3rd paragrah](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)
2. the effect describe pod-node relationship so they must have an agreement on what action to take.

> What impact does it have if:
>
> The node effect is NoSchedule
> kubectl taint nodes node1 key1=value1:NoSchedule
>
> But the POD toleration is NoExecute

Thus in this case the pod and node doesn't have agreement on what to do, so it same effect as not having macthing key=value at all, so pod will not be scheduled at all.

> why do we need to define NoSchedule on the POD? It is already defined on the node.

you don't need to specify the effect on the pod, if you desire the pod has the same effect as whatever the node has.

But you might want to govern another pod differently, I think it makes more sense when multiple taint and toleration comes into play. Reading example on the above docs help me.

That's what I understand. Let me know if there's any misunderstanding.